# Vue3 & i18n: How to use in properties like value and placeholder

Tags: properties, internationalization, vuejs3

I integrated i18n-next in my Vue3 project and it works for elements like headers or labels with the known syntax `{{ $t ("something") }}`, but I can't get it to work with the value or placeholder of things like `<input type="submit" value="This should be variable" class=... />`
What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: As I don't know i18n-next I just post this as a comment: Can't you just bind it like normal attributes and props? `<input type="submit" :value="$t('placeholder')" class=... />`

Comment: This is just the way it works. Thanks a lot - I am pretty new to Vue and I had no idea, that the v-bind directive is the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Thomas mentioned in the above comment, this is how it works:

```
<input type="submit" :value="$t('valuename')" class=.. />
```